# Should the web application be built using microsoft technologies to do Automated testing in Test Manger

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing

To do automation testing using Test Manager and Visual Studio Coded UI Test Project, should the web application be built in .NET technologies?

Comment: No, it's not required to have web application built in .Net to test it using Coded UI.

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as I understand CodedUI just like Selenium drives the browser, so it should work on any website using any back-end technology. Although the browser support is somewhat [limited](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835758.aspx) to specific IE, FireFox and Chrome versions.

Though I would advice in using the same programming language/stack as the website under test, this way the developers can help you better and it might be possible to re-use code of the application for data generation.